# How to make a reverse ordered for loop?

Tags: for-loop, rust

> Editor's note: This question was asked before Rust 1.0 was released and the `..` "range" operator was introduced. The question's code no longer represents the current style, but some answers below uses code that will work in Rust 1.0 and onwards.

I was playing on the [Rust by Example website](https://rustbyexample.com/flow_control/for.html) and wanted to print out fizzbuzz in reverse. Here is what I tried:

```
fn main() {
    // `n` will take the values: 1, 2, ..., 100 in each iteration
    for n in std::iter::range_step(100u, 0, -1) {
        if n % 15 == 0 {
            println!("fizzbuzz");
        } else if n % 3 == 0 {
            println!("fizz");
        } else if n % 5 == 0 {
            println!("buzz");
        } else {
            println!("{}", n);
        }
    }
}
```

There were no compilation errors, but it did not print out anything. How do I iterate from 100 to 1?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

> Editor's note: This question refers to parts of Rust that predate Rust 1.0. Look at other answers for up to date code.

Your code doesn't work because a `uint` of value -1 is equal the maximum value of uint. The range_step iterator stops immediately upon detecting overflow. Using an int fixes this.

```
std::iter::range_step(100i, 0, -1)
```

You can also reverse an iterator with `rev()`.

```
for n in range(0u, 100).rev() { ... }
```

Though note that this will be from 99->0, rather than 100->1.

Comment: So why doesn't the compiler complain about mixing the types?

Comment: @user1452670: You are not mixing types, `100u` is of type `uint`, `0` and `-1` are untyped integrals for which the compiler will *infer* a type. Here, `range_step` requires uniform arguments and receives `(uint, <untyped>, <untyped>)` so the compiler deduces they are all `uint`. If you had *specified* `0i`, or `-1i` then you would have had a mismatch.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: To be fair, the value of `-1` is known to the compiler and "inferring" its type to be `uint` could be made to produce a warning because it's not representable. The question is, how often this is an error or not.

Comment: @sellibitze: Certainly, a lint that would diagnose out-of-range assignments would be very welcome.

Comment: @sellibitze: There has been some [discussion about this on discuss.rust-lang.org](http://discuss.rust-lang.org/t/forbid-unsigned-integer/752).

Comment: The first one is obsolete and the second one is unstable. As things stand in 2022. %)

Comment: The "second one" (.rev()) is stable as of rust 1.0.0, according to documentation. I'm not sure where you're getting your information.

Answer (score 317):

A forward loop is like this:

```
for x in 0..100 {
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

And a reverse loop is done by calling [`Iterator::rev`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.rev) to reverse the order:

```
for x in (0..100).rev() {
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

Comment: in rust, 0..10 means from 0 to 9, 10 is not included. so does (0..10).rev() mean "10 to 1" or "9 to 0"?

Comment: The parentheses help clear this up. The range will be evaluated first (0 to 9), which is then reversed (9 to 0).