# Rust negative for loops?

Tags: rust

Simple question, is it possible to do a for loop on a range of negative values? Specifically starting at -1 and iterating down to some negative value. `for i in -1..x` apparently isn't kosher.

Other than the ugly solution of iterating on the absolute values and then applying the sign within the loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a reverse ordered for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25170091/how-to-make-a-reverse-ordered-for-loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't in the negative numbers, the problem is in the reverse range. If we assume that `x < -1` then you have a range `(a,b)` with `a > b`.

The default step of a rust range in a for loop is `+1`, so the loop never executes. If you write it out, C++ style, you'd be saying

```
for (i=-1; i < x; i++) { ... }
```

So what you want to do is reverse the range:

```rust
for i in (x..=-1).rev()
```

EDIT: Because `(x..-1)` does not include `-1`, we need to change it to `(x..=-1)`. In that case the range will include both `x` and `1`. If we don't want that, we have to fiddle with the `x` bound as well, e.g. `((x+1)..=-1).rev`

Comment: Isn't the `step_by` parameter supposed to be unsigned?

Comment: Whoops. Yes. See my edit. I swear it used to work in the past. That was in the pre-stable days, apparently: https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/step-by-on-negative-numbers/2231

Comment: Note that `for i in (x..-1).rev()` iterates from `-2` down to `x`, since the range `x..-1` does not include the endpoint.

Comment: As Sven Marnach points out, `(x..-1).rev()` starts at **-2**. It should be `(x..=-1).rev()`.

Answer (score 2):

The standard [`Range`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.Range.html) type (what you get with `a..b`) is a half-open *increasing* range. If you have a range where `a >= b`, then the range is empty.

If you want to iterate a range in reverse (decreasing) order, then you need to use [`Iterator::rev`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.rev) to reverse the range, which is enabled by range being a [`DoubleEndedIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.DoubleEndedIterator.html) and providing the reverse iteration [`next_back`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.DoubleEndedIterator.html#tymethod.next_back).

So in this case, you'd iterate over `((x + 1)..0).rev()`.

Just as a fun side note, you can also get basically any iterator you want out of [`iter::successors`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/fn.successors.html), by just providing a `fn next(&T) -> Option<T>`; in this case, `|x| x - 1`, if that's clearer in a specific use case than reversing an increasing range.

Comment: `(x..-1).rev()` will start at **-2**. You need to use `(x..=-1).rev()` instead.