# Dynamically create a range in either direction in Rust

Tags: rust, iterator, range

I am learning Rust and recently went through an exercise where I had to iterate through numbers that could go in either direction. I tried the below with unexpected results.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32
}

fn test() {
    let p1 = Point { x: 1, y: 8 };
    let p2 = Point { x: 3, y: 6 };

    let all_x = p1.x..=p2.x;
    println!("all_x: {:?}", all_x.clone().collect::<Vec<i32>>());
    let all_y = p1.y..=p2.y;
    println!("all_y: {:?}", all_y.clone().collect::<Vec<i32>>());
    
    let points: Vec<Point> = all_x.zip(all_y).map(|(x, y)| Point { x, y }).collect();

    println!("points: {:?}", points);
}
```

The output was

```
all_x: [1, 2, 3]
all_y: []
points: []
```

After some googling I found an [explanation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/9555) and some [old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25170091/how-to-make-a-reverse-ordered-for-loop-in-rust) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42545548/how-can-i-iterate-over-a-backwards-range) which basically amount to use `(a..b).rev()` as needed.

My question is, how do I do this in a dynamic way? If I use an `if...else` like so

```rust
let all_x = if p1.x < p2.x { (p1.x..=p2.x) } else { (p2.x..=p1.x).rev() };
```

I get a type error because the `else` is different than the `if`

```
   |
58 |       let all_x = if p1.x < p2.x { (p1.x..=p2.x) }
   |                   -                ------------- expected because of this
   |  _________________|
   | |
59 | |     else { (p2.x..=p1.x).rev() };
   | |____________^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^_- `if` and `else` have incompatible types
   |              |
   |              expected struct `RangeInclusive`, found struct `Rev`
   |
   = note: expected type `RangeInclusive<_>`
            found struct `Rev<RangeInclusive<_>>`
```

After trying a bunch of different variations on `let all_x: dyn Range<Item = i32>`, `let all_x: dyn Iterator<Item = i32>`, etc, the only way I have managed to do this is by turning them into collections and then back to iterators.

```rust
let all_x: Vec<i32>;
if p1.x < p2.x { all_x = (p1.x..=p2.x).collect(); }
else { all_x = (p2.x..=p1.x).rev().collect(); }
let all_x = all_x.into_iter();
println!("all_x: {:?}", all_x.clone().collect::<Vec<i32>>());

let all_y: Vec<i32>;
if p1.y < p2.y { all_y = (p1.y..=p2.y).collect(); }
else { all_y = (p2.y..=p1.y).rev().collect(); }
let all_y = all_y.into_iter();
println!("all_y: {:?}", all_y.clone().collect::<Vec<i32>>());
```

which provides the desired outcome

```
all_x: [1, 2, 3]
all_y: [8, 7, 6]
points: [Point { x: 1, y: 8 }, Point { x: 2, y: 7 }, Point { x: 3, y: 6 }]
```

but is a bit repetitive, inelegant and I'm assuming not very efficient at large numbers. Is there a better way to handle this situation?

*NOTE: Sorry for including the `Point` struct. I could not get my example to work with `x1`, `x2`, etc. Probably a different question for a different post lol.*

Comment: Advent of code hehe :)

Comment: @Netwave haha, you got me. I tried to scrub as much of that from my example as possible, but the timing doesn't lie.

Comment: Also see https://users.rust-lang.org/t/range-and-reversed-range/17309 for a more compact question example, and a few other solutions not mentioned on this page. And I admit, I also came on this page because of Advent of code :)

Comment: I found this article (for AoC also) https://kaylynn.gay/blog/post/rust_ranges_and_suffering where the author needed this also for AoC. This article explain well the problem and is a good read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can dynamically dispatch it. Wrapping them into a `Box` and returning a dynamic object, an `Iterator` in this case. For example:

```rust
fn maybe_reverse_range(init: usize, end: usize, reverse: bool) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item=usize>> {
    if reverse {
        Box::new((init..end).rev())
    } else {
        Box::new((init..end))
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e91e05bee17f35225cd8629c22fa580e)

Comment: Thanks! I should have paid more attention to `Box` in The Book. I made a version that automatically flipped these based on `init` and `end` for my case, but this was spot on.

Comment: To be clear for people like me who got confused on range.rev(): rev() does *not* reverse the range (it doesn't transform init..end into end..init), it just iterates backward. So if init >= end and init..end is empty, then (init..end).rev() still iterates on nothing. You need to manually swap init and end based on their comparison to get the range you want. Then, applying rev() is optional, do it only if you need to iterate backward.

Comment: Of course, this example demonstrates dynamic dispatch for an Iterator, so it only makes sense because we rev().

Answer (score 7):

The enum `itertools::Either` can be used to solve the incompatible type error in the if/else statement. A function like `get_range_iter` below using `Either` can reduce the code repetition.

```
use itertools::Either;
fn get_range_iter(start: i32, end: i32) -> impl Iterator<Item=i32> {
    if start < end {
        Either::Left(start..=end)
    } else {
        Either::Right((end..=start).rev())
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32
}

fn main() {
    let p1 = Point { x: 1, y: 8 };
    let p2 = Point { x: 3, y: 6 };

    let all_x = get_range_iter(p1.x, p2.x);
    let all_y = get_range_iter(p1.y, p2.y);

    println!("all_x: {:?}", all_x.collect::<Vec<_>>());
    println!("all_y: {:?}", all_y.collect::<Vec<_>>());

}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4f2815458bf69ada40f2f60aa78c4a34)