# How to define generic Iterator or Range variable in Rust?

Tags: rust

Having input data of two numbers, I need to construct either an iterator or a range and pass it further:

```rust
// ordering is not strictly defined
let x1: usize = 4;
let x2: usize = 2;

let mut x_range = ...;

if x1 < x2 {
    x_range = (x1..=x2);
}
else {
    // i.e if we have ((x1, x2) == (3,1) it should produce 3,2,1 sequence.
    x_range = (x2..=x1).rev();
}

for x in x_range {
// do something
}
```

The problem is that two variants of ranges produced by regular range expression and `rev()` have different types and throw type errors further in the code.

So I tried to define the range.

```rust
let mut x_range: std::ops::Range<usize>;
```

But received the error of `= note: expected struct std::ops::Range<usize> found struct RangeInclusive<usize>`:

Then I tried to define an Iterator and then convert ranges with `into_iter()`.

```rust
let mut x_range: dyn Iterator<usize>;
```

But then I received `doesn't have a size known at compile-time`

So is there any way to pass an abstract parent interface of an iterator or a range to other functions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70238996/dynamically-create-a-range-in-either-direction-in-rust/70241464#70241464

Comment: Yeah, that should do the trick! Though I think that vanilla way without external crate from Cormac answer is preferable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Rust Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/trait-object.html):

> Due to the opaqueness of which concrete type the value is of, trait objects are dynamically sized types. Like all DSTs, trait objects are used behind some type of pointer; for example &dyn SomeTrait or Box. Each instance of a pointer to a trait object includes:
>
> - a pointer to an instance of a type T that implements SomeTrait
> - a virtual method table, often just called a vtable, which contains, for each method of SomeTrait and its supertraits that T implements, a pointer to T's implementation (i.e. a function pointer).
>
> The purpose of trait objects is to permit "late binding" of methods. Calling a method on a trait object results in virtual dispatch at runtime: that is, a function pointer is loaded from the trait object vtable and invoked indirectly. The actual implementation for each vtable entry can vary on an object-by-object basis.

---

The concrete type of `dyn Iterator` could be any size, so Rust doesn't know how to store it on the stack. You need a level of indirection (a pointer or reference) with a fixed size. In this case, there are a couple probable solutions:

1. **A boxed trait object.** This is written like:

   ```rust
   let x_range: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = usize>> = if x1 < x2 {
       Box::new(x1..=x2)
   } else {
       Box::new((x2..=x1).rev())
   };
   ```

   Rust will move the concrete type to the heap and store a trait object which on the stack (see [the relevant chapter in the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html)). This is generally the simplest option.
2. **An enum with its own `Iterator` impl.** If the set of concrete types is closed and fairly small (as in your case), you can write a type that holds either possible concrete type:

   ```rust
   enum MyIterator {
      Forward(RangeInclusive<usize>),
      Reverse(Rev<RangeInclusive<usize>>),
   }

   impl Iterator for MyIterator {
       type Item = usize;

       fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
           match self {
               MyIterator::Forward(ref mut it) => it.next(),
               MyIterator::Reverse(ref mut it) => it.next(),
           }
       }
   }

   let x_range = if x1 < x2 {
       MyIterator::Forward(x1..=x2)
   } else {
       MyIterator::Reverse((x2..=x1).rev())
   };
   ```

   This is a *very slightly* more efficient solution than the boxed trait object, as it doesn't require a heap allocation and there's one fewer level of indirection to call `Iterator::next`. That efficiency gain is probably insignificant unless you're calling `next()` in a very hot loop.

Comment: syntax edit suggest: I think `Box<dyn Iterator<Item = usize>> ` is valid, the `Box<dyn Iterator<Item = <usize>>> ` version doesn't compile.

Comment: Is there a way to return a pointer without "boxing" it?