# Create range higher to lower

Tags: rust, iterator, range

I want to create range `x..y` where `x > y`. For eg `5..-10`.

`5..-10` produces empty range https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.Range.html

I created this questions to share my solution and potentially someone will come with better idea.

Comment: Also a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70329833/range-where-start-end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can create valid range `y..x` (since `x > y`) and then reverse it

```
(y..x).rev()
```

this will produce desired range