# What happens when one reverse the range in Rust?

Tags: rust

In Rust, this code compiles and runs but generates no error or output:

```rust
fn main() {
    for number in 4..1 {
        println!("{}!", number);
    }
}
```

Shouldn't Rust consider this as invalid code and not compile or give a warning since it also doesn't seem to understand that I want to iterate in reverse?

This code generates no Assembly output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Range where start > end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70329833/range-where-start-end)

Comment: I think he asked for an explanation instead of a fix

Comment: For what it is worth, `cargo clippy` warns about that with a [`reversed_empty_ranges`](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#reversed_empty_ranges) and suggests writing `(1..4).rev()` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's see what happens internally.

```rust
4..1
```

is actually just syntactical sugar for

```rust
std::ops::Range { start: 4, end: 1 }
```

Which is [defined as](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.Range.html):

> The range start..end contains all values with start <= x < end. It is empty if start >= end.

Therefore, as specified in the documentation, `for 4..1` should do nothing, as it always iterates forwards and the start is already past the end.

To iterate backwards, use:

```rust
(1..4).rev()
```

Comment: It might be slightly unintuitive to the original poster that `(1..4).rev()` _does not_ result in the range `[4, 3, 2]`. Do you think it should be clarified in your answer?

Comment: @VincentSavard Might be. Unsure what to do about that.
Tbh I think it's quite self-explanatory if you look at the definition of `Range`.